# excel file with the ability to filter columns

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, styleframe

I need to create excel with columns that can be filited.

prefer to use openpyxl since I already use StyleFrame to style the excel.

[example](http://postimg.org/image/uhx7lbvt7/)

Comment: Filters are supported by openpyxl.

Comment: class openpyxl.worksheet.filters.AutoFilter [link](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/2.0/openpyxl.worksheet.html#module-openpyxl.worksheet.filters)

Comment: thank you very much it works!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the solution using StyleFrame, I had to use the "row_to_add_filters" with index 0 to add filters to the columns....

```
from StyleFrame import StyleFrame, colors

excel_writer = StyleFrame.ExcelWriter('example.xlsx')
sf = StyleFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [1, 1, 1], 'c': [2, 3, 4]})
sf.apply_column_style(cols_to_style=['a', 'c'], protection=True, style_header=True)
sf.apply_style_by_indexes(indexes_to_style=2, cols_to_style='b', bg_color=colors.yellow, protection=True)
sf.to_excel(excel_writer=excel_writer, row_to_add_filters=0, columns_and_rows_to_freeze='B2', allow_protection=True)
excel_writer.save()
```

Answer (score -2):

This code is using xlwt.
It writes lines and colums.

```
import xlwt

def writelineSimple(shet,line, lstLine):
    col=0
    for elem in lstLine:
        shet.write(line, col, elem)
        col=col+1

def writecolum(shet,line,col, lstLine):
    for elem in lstLine:
        shet.write(line, col, elem)
        line=line+1

def writeline(shet,line,col, lstLine):
    for elem in lstLine:
        shet.write(line, col, elem)
        col=col+1


book = xlwt.Workbook(encoding="utf-8")
sheet1 = book.add_sheet("Sheet 1")

writelineSimple(sheet1,0,["col1","col2","col3","col4","col5"])
writelineSimple(sheet1,1,["writelineSimple1","writelineSimple2"])
writeline(sheet1,3,3,["writeline1","writeline2","writeline3"])
writecolum(sheet1,5,5,["writecolum1","writecolum2","writecolum3"])


book.save("myfirstgeneratedexcel.xls")
```

**myfirstgeneratedexcel.xls**

```
col1    col2    col3    col4    col5    
writelineSimple1    writelineSimple2                

            writeline1  writeline2  writeline3

                    writecolum1
                    writecolum2
                    writecolum3
```

Comment: xlwt doesn't support XLSX files.